# Body class helper

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to replicate the following Ruby on Rails helper:

```
def body_classes
    "c-#{params[:controller].underscore} is-#{params[:action].underscore}"
end
```

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
def body_classes(conn) do
    "l- is-#{action_name(conn)}"
end
```

How can I retrieve the layout/view name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for [Phoenix.Controller.controller_module/1](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#controller_module/1) or [Phoenix.Controller.view_module/1](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#view_module/1) and [Phoenix.Controller.action_name/1](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Controller.html#action_name/1).

```
"l- #{controller_module(conn)}-#{action_name(conn)}"
```

You can use [Phoenix.Naming.resource_name/2](http://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Naming.html#resource_name/2) if you want just the verb.

Something like:

```
Phoenix.Naming.resource_name(MyApp.UserController, "Controller") #"user"
```

The end code would look like:

```
"l-#{controller_module(conn) |> Phoenix.Naming.resource_name("Controller")}-#{action_name(conn)}"
#"l-user-index"
```